# How to run 2 scripts in a job from Hudson master?

Tags: hudson

I have implemented Hudson master, slave job configuration and it is working fine. In which i have to run 2 scripts in a job from hudson master. can you help me is there possibility to run 2 scripts? as well both scripts are dependencies like the second should run after the first script executed.

Thanks in advance - sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is include the script as a build step in your current build for example.

1. Pull down source
2. Build it
3. Run the script, as part of the build step.

This option is only available for Free Style Jobs.

[image]

Here is where the scripts would go or path to script to execute.

Goodluck.